# Can't read a response from a request (Discord JS)

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I can't get a response value from my request.
The method works fine, but whenever I try to get the value to the embed it doesn't work.

CODE:

```js
async execute(interaction) {
  const ip = interaction.options.getString('server-ip');
  const port = interaction.options.getString('port');

  util.status(ip, parseInt(port)).then((result) => {
    const embed = new EmbedBuilder()
      .setThumbnail('attachment://favicon.png')
      .setColor('#BFCDEB')
      .setTitle('Mc server status')
      .addFields(
        { name: 'Players Online', value: online },
        { name: 'Max Player Cap', value: result.players.max },
        { name: 'Server Version', value: result.version.name },
        { name: 'MOTD', value: result.motd.clean },
        {
          name: 'Ping (from proxies like bungee/waterfall)',
          value: result.roundTripLatency,
        },
      )
      .setFooter('MC Server Checker');
  });

  interaction.channel.send(embed);
}
```

I've tried to get the value as a const but it won't work

Comment: interaction.channel.send(embed) is not working

Comment: because it should be `send({ embeds: [embed] })`

Comment: @ZsoltMeszaros it's not working, ReferenceError: embed is not defined &,         errors: [ [ 'value', [ValidationError] ] ]

Comment: I think it's not using the embed const, that's why it's not defined

Comment: You should really indent your code properly. :) You should send the embed inside that `then`, it's not available outside of that.

Comment: @ZsoltMeszaros I think I understand what you're saying but if I do that it doesn't execute the ``interaction.channel.send(embed)``

Answer (score 0):

It works fine if you do like this:

```
async execute(interaction) {


const ip = interaction.options.getString('server-ip');
  const port = interaction.options.getString('port');

  util.status(ip, parseInt(port)).then((result) => {
    const embed = new EmbedBuilder()
      .setThumbnail('attachment://favicon.png')
      .setColor('#BFCDEB')
      .setTitle('Mc server status')
      .addFields(
        { name: 'Players Online', value: online },
        { name: 'Max Player Cap', value: result.players.max },
        { name: 'Server Version', value: result.version.name },
        { name: 'MOTD', value: result.motd.clean },
        {
          name: 'Ping (from proxies like bungee/waterfall)',
          value: result.roundTripLatency,
        },
      )
      .setFooter('MC Server Checker');
      interaction.channel.send(embed);

  });

  
}
```

I just had to put the `interaction.channel.send(send)` in`.then()` promise